# Python selenium Action chains

Tags: selenium

I m new to python selenium
I m learning pytest framework. I am able to automate textbox and write test cases for that. But when it comes to automating mouse hover actions I am not able to do that. Can anyone send a code for pytest framework for Action chains driver how to write code for it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **ActionChain**

```
element_to_hover = driver.find_element_by_id("some id")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover).perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Please read it more from [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

**Example :**

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")
hidden_submenu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav #submenu1")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).click(hidden_submenu).perform()
```

Comment: Well thanks for your reply. I know how to use Action chain. But what i m not able to do is to figure out how to use the Action chain method inside the pytest framework

Comment: When you import `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains` you do not get the option to use action chains ?